# $.fadeOut() fails in Opera if img has negative margin in table

Tags: jquery, opera, fadeout

It seems that an image with style margins, in Opera, prevents `$.fadeOut()` from working properly.

jsFiddle update 15, still not working in Opera: http://jsfiddle.net/fmaUZ/15/

cleaned some tags

Comment: Share the code with us in order to get help. Use jsFiddle.net and give us an URL

Comment: What a great question! Try using `.animate({opacity:0}, speed);` instead?

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmaUZ/6/
click on the little image

Comment: I've updated your fiddle so it's cleaner (moving parts to where they should be): http://jsfiddle.net/fmaUZ/8/ Note, there is no reason to have that `<script>` tag *within* the `table` markup, and I believe that is not valid markup. Additionally, do not use `window.onload` to set page load handlers with jQuery, as that causes known problems; use `$(window).load()`.

Comment: Also, refrain from using inline markup event syntax like `<a onclick="doStuff();"`, instead use the [appropriate jQuery event handler](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) syntax.

Comment: I know that removing the css.class that set margins, it works. but i need this css.class in Opera too..

Comment: you have deleted this .Strumento {cursor:pointer; margin-right: -8px;}

Comment: You're right; my apologies. Here is the corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/fmaUZ/9/ I ended up combining two fiddles when I saw the last `script` tag. I've fixed it in the question. And yes, I see it doesn't fire now.

Comment: as expected, not working in Opera 11.61

Answer (score 0):

Ok, below I've made some changes based on how you would normally approach this in a jQuery "way":

First, I fixed the `img` margin issue by moving it to the parent `td` and using `padding`. I don't know why Opera failed to fire the event handler with your code/markup/css, just that this was how I was able to fix it with the same visual effect.

Note, when I [modify my below code](http://jsfiddle.net/fmaUZ/13/) to do:

```
.Strumento img {
     margin-right: -8px;
}
```

It appears to work fine in Opera. So I don't actually know what the specific problem is here, but I suspect it has something to do with the actual event attachment itself.

**CSS/Markup**

```
.Strumento {
    cursor:pointer;  
    padding-left: 8px; 
}

<td class="Strumento">
    <img id="obj_BJOQvk" title="-" src="http://www.poketown.net/public/poketown/oggettinoprova2.gif">
</td>
```

**jQuery**

I also adjusted your script so that it's not using inline event syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Sets browser infos as html.className
    var params = [];

    $.each($.browser, function(k, v) {
        var pat = /^[a-z].*/i;
        if (pat.test(k)) {
            params.push(k);
        }
    });

    params = params.join(' ');
    $('html').addClass(params);

    $('tbody .nodeco').click(function(){
        $('#boh3').attr('checked', false);
    });
    $('thead .nodeco').click(function(){
        $('tbody .nodeco').attr('checked', true);
    });
    $('.Strumento img').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
$(window).load(function(){
    Nifty("div#header","small");
    Nifty("div#header2","small");
    Nifty("div#header3","small");
    Nifty("div#header4","small");
    Nifty("div#dati,div#dati2","same-height");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmaUZ/12/

Comment: Your problem is the negative margin. See the style that I used in the fiddle below my answer.